# Force autoplay video to continue when switching tabs on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I have an HTML5 video tag with the attributes `autoplay loop muted playsinline`. In iOS the video stops playing, if the user switches to another browser tab. However it doesn't start again when switching back.

I tried listening for different events such as `window.onfocus()` and then manually starting the video with the `play()` method, however these events do not seem to fire, until the user actually clicks inside the document again, and so they are virtually useless in this case.

This site has an HTML5 video tag in the hero: https://www.stoxenergy.com/en/technology/
However that one keeps playing, even when the user switches tabs.

I can't figure out how they do it. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you test your video using their URL (_eg:_ `https://videos.ctfassets.net/...etc...mp4`)? Does setting up as `autoplay="" loop="" playsinline="" muted=""` in your video tag change anything?

Comment: Doesn't make any difference.